# Laravel: Need help in logical programming terms(Email Sending)

Tags: jquery, database, laravel, email

I attached some codes here. So, basically i need send mail after few days( the days will detect from database) to user that they never sign in after register the system. My problem nw is i feel illogical with my code at below. **$mail->days** this referring to DB.

```
if( $user->created_at < Carbon::now()->subDays($mail->days)){  

                        $ableToSendMail = false;
                    }
```

So, i try in another way the to send mail to the user. The method that i used is in table i have a column called last_sign_in which is it's will detect last seen of user but the problem is i will make that send the mail after fews days. Like i need implemented this like in this code **Carbon::now()->subDays($mail->days)**. Anyone can help me?

```
  if(is_null($user->last_sign_in)){

         $ableToSendMail = true;
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Edited

```
protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)
    {
        $schedule->call('App\Http\Controllers\YourController@yourmethod')->weekly();
    }
```

on YourController.php

```
public function yourmethod()
{
$inactive = App\Users::whereNull('last_login')->pluck('email');

Mail::to($inactive)->queue(new MailTemplate);
}
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for suggestion. there is any example for this to understand more because I'm new to laravel.

Comment: the official link i've provided is very straightforward but if you need a demo video, search on youtube "laravel scheduling"

Comment: ok, probably just point the schedule to your controller method  E.g. $schedule->call('App\Http\Controllers\YourController@method')->weekly();, then on your method, query those users with null last_login, then send email